# Using a pre-declared variable in another variable declaration in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simplified a longer query to this.

I would like to use a pre-declared variable in another variable declaration. This is what I have done.

```
DECLARE @FRUIT VARCHAR(10) = 'apple'

DECLARE @sql3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT('select ', @FRUIT)

EXEC(@sql3)
```

I was expecting it to give me the result as 'apple' - but I get this error instead:

> Invalid column name 'apple'.

Please suggest a way how to solve this. Thanks

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Added. Microsoft SQL

Comment: Try wrapping your `@FRUIT` value with single quote. You will need to write `'` for escape sequence. Try like below.
`DECLARE @sql3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT('select ''', @FRUIT, '''')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EXEC sp_executesql` and pass variable like below.

```
DECLARE @FRUIT VARCHAR(10) = 'apple'

-- Use @FRUIT itself and not its value
DECLARE @sql3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'select @FRUIT'    

EXEC sp_executesql @sql3, N'@FRUIT VARCHAR(10)', @FRUIT
```

---

Alternatively if you want to use only value from that variable and don't want to pass variable to `exec` then try wrapping your `@FRUIT` value with single quote. You will need to write `'` twice for escape sequence. Try like below.

```
DECLARE @FRUIT VARCHAR(10) = 'apple'

-- Wrap value of @FRUIT with ''
DECLARE @sql3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONCAT('select ''', @FRUIT, '''') 

EXEC(@sql3)
```

Comment: Your first solution works too.  Thank you

Comment: Rather than wrapping quotes manually, it's much better to do `CONCAT('select ', QUOTENAME(@FRUIT, ''''))`. Obviously the first option of using a parameter is the best

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I tried this and it works.

```
DECLARE @FRUIT varchar(10) = ' ''apple'' '

DECLARE @sql3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'select '+ @FRUIT

EXEC(@sql3)
```